# FBNativeAdView is not presented - Swift

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-audience-network

I am trying to present Facebook Native Ad Template with no luck.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, FBNativeAdDelegate
{
    override func viewDidLoad()
   {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        facebookAdViewContainer.backgroundColor = UIColor.greenColor()
        let nativeAd = FBNativeAd(placementID: <id>)
        nativeAd.delegate = self
        nativeAd.loadAd()
        ...
   }

   func nativeAdDidLoad(nativeAd: FBNativeAd) 
   {
       let attributes = FBNativeAdViewAttributes()
       attributes.backgroundColor = UIColor.blueColor()
       let adview = FBNativeAdView(nativeAd: nativeAd, withType:FBNativeAdViewType.GenericHeight300)//, withAttributes: attributes)
       adview.hidden = false
       self.topBannerViewContainer.addSubview(adview)
   }
...
}
```

As you can see in the picture, the ad is not showing. At least I would expect to see blue background of the ad, but all I can see is the green background of the container

[image]

Comment: Is self.topBannerViewContainer non nil? What is the width of the adview before adding it?

Comment: Perhaps it is a height issue as suggested here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33735430/504521

Comment: @BrianTrzupek, Thank you for your comment, but the height of topBannerViewContainer is bigger then 300

Comment: roger that. I did manage to solve my problem of it not loading (and I have no idea if it impacts your challenge). Basically, I am loading ads into a 'feed view' where a user can scroll though a bunch of content. Every N items an ad will appear. FB was only responding to the first ad request of mine. So I needed to break them off serially (after each returned, request the next) and then it was able to return the proper amount of ads. However, it presented in a similar fashion to yours - it just didn't show anything for the 2nd-N ad units.