# Facebook Native Ads FBNativeAdsManagerDelegate implementation methods did not called

Tags: ios, objective-c, facebook, facebook-audience-network

`FBNativeAdsManagerDelegate` in Facebook Native Ads working properly in `UIViewController` class but when used in custom NSObject class its not working i.e. its delegate methods `nativeAdsLoaded` and `nativeAdsFailedToLoadWithError` did not get called.

**CustomFBAd.h** file

```
@import FBAudienceNetwork;

#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@protocol OnFBNativeAdLoadedDelegate<NSObject>

- (void)onFBNativeAdLoaded:(UIView *)adView;

@end

@interface CustomFBAd : NSObject

@property (nonatomic,weak) id <OnFBNativeAdLoadedDelegate>delegate;

-(void)requestNativeAd:(NSString *)FaceBookPlacementID;
@end
```

**CustomFBAd.m** file

```
#import "CustomFBAd.h"

@interface CustomFBAd ()<FBNativeAdsManagerDelegate,FBNativeAdDelegate>

@property (nonatomic, strong) FBNativeAdsManager *manager;
@property (nonatomic, weak) FBNativeAdScrollView *scrollView;

@end
@implementation CustomFBAd

-(void)requestNativeAd:(NSString *)FaceBookPlacementID{
    if(FaceBookPlacementID.length != 0){
        FBNativeAdsManager *manager = [[FBNativeAdsManager alloc] initWithPlacementID:FaceBookPlacementID forNumAdsRequested:5];
        manager.delegate = self;
        [FBAdSettings addTestDevice:@"cf1bb93becbe6e31f26fdf7d80d19b4ae225afaa"];
        [manager loadAds];
        self.manager = manager;
    }
}

#pragma mark - FBNativeAdDelegate implementation

- (void)nativeAdDidClick:(FBNativeAd *)nativeAd
{
    //    NSLog(@"Native ad was clicked.");
}

- (void)nativeAdDidFinishHandlingClick:(FBNativeAd *)nativeAd
{
    //    NSLog(@"Native ad did finish click handling.");
}

- (void)nativeAdWillLogImpression:(FBNativeAd *)nativeAd
{
    //    NSLog(@"Native ad impression is being captured.");
}

#pragma mark FBNativeAdsManagerDelegate

-(void)nativeAdDidLoad:(FBNativeAd *)nativeAd
{

}

- (void)nativeAdsLoaded
{
    NSLog(@"Native ads loaded, constructing native UI...");

    if (self.scrollView) {
        [self.scrollView removeFromSuperview];
        self.scrollView = nil;
    }

    FBNativeAdScrollView *scrollView = [[FBNativeAdScrollView alloc] initWithNativeAdsManager:self.manager withType:FBNativeAdViewTypeGenericHeight120];
    scrollView.xInset = 0;
    scrollView.delegate = self;
    self.scrollView = scrollView;

    [self.delegate onFBNativeAdLoaded:self.scrollView];
}

- (void)nativeAdsFailedToLoadWithError:(NSError *)error
{
    NSLog(@"Native ads failed to load with error: %@", error);
}

@end
```

As stated in above code I did set **FBNativeAdsManager**'s delegate in `requestNativeAd` method as

```
manager.delegate = self;
```

And also used as **FBNativeAdsManagerDelegate,FBNativeAdDelegate**

```
@interface CustomFBAd ()<FBNativeAdsManagerDelegate,FBNativeAdDelegate>
```

And call this code as

```
    CustomFBAd *objFBAd = [[CustomFBAd alloc]init];
    objFBAd.delegate = self;
    [objFBAd requestNativeAd:@"my_FB_placement_Id"];
```

any clue (Note : same code works if I use it in `UIViewController`)? Thanks

Comment: After two days still is there anyone from Facebook who can answer?

Comment: if your delegate methods are called in uiviewcontroller, than there is a problem with the code. I guess you have to have a strong reference of CustomFBAd in your controller. Because none of other references are taking hold of your CustomFBAd. hope it helps :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your delegate methods are called in uiviewcontroller, than there is a problem with the code. I guess you have to have a strong reference of CustomFBAd in your controller. Because none of other references are taking hold of your CustomFBAd. hope it helps

Answer (score 3):

Finally it works after making strong reference of `CustomFBAd` it works like a charm(Thanks to @MuhammadZohaibEhsan).So init `CustomFBAd` as

```
@property(nonatomic, strong) CustomFBAd * objFBAd;
```

And change

```
    CustomFBAd *objFBAd = [[CustomFBAd alloc]init];
    objFBAd.delegate = self;
    [objFBAd requestNativeAd:@"my_FB_placement_Id"];
```

to

```
    self.objFBAd = [[CustomFBAd alloc]init];
    self.objFBAd.delegate = self;
    [self.objFBAd requestNativeAd:@"my_FB_placement_Id"];
```

Comment: Can i post this as a answer :)

Comment: Saved me finally. Thankyou :)